# Does it suck to not provide graceful errors to a user who doesn't use the website properly?

Tags: asp.net, user-interface, usability

I recently received a feedback from a colleague about my source code of a website. He says that it is a bad practice to not handle gracefully what visual interface does not allow to do.

Since it's not very clear, here's an example.

Let's say a visitor can comment something.

- A comment is saved into a database, in a `nvarchar(500)` column.
- The `<input />` field length is limited to 500.

But, of course, nothing forbids to a more advanced user to *disable the length limit* and to type 501 character.

(Other examples: submitting an option which does not even exist in a `<select />`. *But* there *is* a graceful error when the user is asked to enter a number, and she enters a non-number instead, since keypress events are controlled through JavaScript, and JavaScript may be disabled)

If the visitor does so, there would be a failure on code contracts level. The AJAX request would fail with an unexpected error (or, on page submit, there will be an unexpected error). In all cases, the visitor will see that something wrong happened, but will have no graceful message indicating that the length of the submitted comment is too long.

Why is it bad practice? Why would I bother to design clear and explicit error messages for the cases where the visitor who uses correctly the website will never have?

---

Note: I understand that it sucks to display a .NET Framework detailed error and a stack trace when something like this happens. If I do so, it's a serious security issue. But in my case, there is just an AJAX response with something very generic or a redirect to a generic page with the apologizes about an error.

Comment: You're kidding right? Sounds like you just don't want to do the work. A user shouldn't have to see a bunch of code errors. You should have proper error checking in place which shouldn't allow users to do things that they clearly shouldn't. You should check this on the frontend (JavaScript) and backend. If a user bypasses the javascript checks somehow, your system should catch it before attempting to submit it to the DB.

Comment: @xil3 - Did you even read the question? It states that it's being protected on the FrontEnd using maxlength and on the backend using code contracts. He is asking if he should display a  formatted (andpotentially translated) error message for a scenario that could only be caused by a malicious user.

Comment: @MainMa - I think you need to rephrase your question, as every answer here has missed the point.

Comment: @Richard Yea I did read it, and wrote that based on what I understood. It wasn't a very clear question, hence why I added it as a comment...

Comment: @xil3 - You aren't wrong there.

Comment: I just re-read it again and based on what he wrote, there isn't any indication that he's doing any back-end validation. `If the visitor does so, there would be a failure on code contracts level. The AJAX request would fail with an unexpected error (or, on page submit, there will be an unexpected error).` - shouldn't be an 'unexpected' error if it's validated on the back-end. If it was submitted via AJAX with 501, the back-end should handle it properly and not just fail.

Comment: @xil3 - Code contracts will throw an exception if the validation fails. The error returned contains no exception information (he mentions that in the note at the bottom). He is asking if the error needs a custom error message.

Comment: "Does it suck?" what is this, Digg?

Comment: As an aside: In my experience as a user I prefer it when a text field doesn't restrict what I type, but instead checks the fields when I press submit (aborting and highlighting bad fields if anything is wrong).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since everyone appears to be missing your actual question, I'll put in my 2c (though I'll no doubt be downvoted in retaliation)

As long as your inputs are validated server side (your client-side maxlength is probably ok, though some obscure browsers may not support it), you can return a generic error message as long as it contains no exception information (which you have stated it doesn't).

If, however, it's possible to fail validation via lack of javascript or incorrect entry, then a custom error message should be provided for the sake of the user's sanity.

In short, what you are doing is fine.

Answer (score 4):

First an most importantly

**You should validate everything the user supplies on the server!  This means not letting 501 letters through**

Other than that if an unhandled exception occurs you should show the user a message *which gives nothing away*.  If you were to return exception information this is **gold dust to an attacker**.

The best method is to display a general error such as "We're sorry, we're working on the problem straight away" and e-mail the exception information to the developers in order for them to fix it.

Comment: The question specifies that the long entry would be caught. He is asking if a user friendly message should be displayed for a situation where the user is clearly messing with the system.

Comment: If a user knows how to mess with your application you certainly shouldn't be helping them, you therefore should be only displaying a generic message

Comment: What do you mean by "validate"? If I use code contracts to restrict the length to 500 characters, it means that the user would hardly be able to go further than the business layer when submitting 501 letters. Even if she does so, the database column is restricted to 500 characters (even if I don't like the idea to send to the database a request which *will* fail for sure).

Comment: In your situation the code contracts are protecting you - but you should also be looking to use controls such as the ASP.NET validation controls.  This ensures the non-valid data is stopped at the first possibility.

Comment: @MainMa you should have front-end and back-end validation, not just front-end.

Comment: -1 While nothing you've said is incorrect, you've missed the entire  point of the question. The question states that he is not returning exception information and that the validation is protected server side.

Answer (score 2):

> Why would I bother to design clear and explicit error messages for the cases where the visitor who uses correctly the website will never have?

If everyone used the web correctly, we'd never need to have validation.

As Ronald Reagan once said, "Trust, but verify".

Put in server-side validation for the length of fields. Put in validation to make sure there aren't any XSS or SQL Injection attacks.  It's not the people who use your site correctly that you have to worry about, it's the ones that use it maliciously.

Comment: -1 The OP stated that he is using code contracts. He is asking whether a specific error code should be returned, or if a generic failure (with no exception information) is fine.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the largest part of the problem is that you are assuming that validation should only be happening in the UI.  It really is best to validate in the UI *and* the backend.  There is no need to return a stack trace or detailed exception information.  On Page_Load(), you should always be validating all user input again and displaying the information statically, as if the user has disabled JavaScript.

Comment: I know the question is not 100% clear, but he is clearly making no such assumption.

Comment: We all understand that we "missed the point" of the question, but I find it slightly rude that you had to take the time to point that out on every other response other than your own, and even say that you were downvoting others.  Let your answer stand on its own merit.  Regardless if you are the only one who "got it", there is still plenty of valuable information in these posts.

Comment: The lack of understanding of the question is the only reason I added an answer and, frankly, I found it rude that almost all the answers misread the question and _then_ insinuated that the OP was somehow lazy or otherwise incompetent. I added "-1" comments because I don't like it when people are downvoted anonymously. On an unrelated note, if you prefix your comment with @Richard (only the first 3 characters matter) I'll be automatically notified.

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing isn't just bad practice, it's bad design. If you can anticipate an error or exception, then you should anticipate methods of handling it, mitigating it or alleviating it. This goes for any interface design whether it's for a website or a refrigerator. If a visitor gets a generic error and is given no insight as to how to fix it, then why should that person bother using your website? If they're forced to (for work reasons maybe), then all you've done is alienate your customer and give yourself a bad name.

I would suggest you ask yourself why you're not handling these very easy to control situations. Is it laziness or do you just lack experience as a user?

Comment: What you're describing is not what he is describing.

Answer (score 0):

Server side validation is for two main purposes:

- as a graceful degradation if the client validation doesn't work for some reason

  - in this case, you want a nice user-friendly message
- as a security measure to ensure malicious clients can't damage your system.

  - in this case, you want no internal details displayed

If you want to take the route of true graceful degradation, it would be NICE if the server still gave back the user a friendly message for each validation.

In the case of maxLength, this is not very likely to be needed. But many kinds of validation use Javascript, and there are still those people or platforms that don't support Javascript. Older mobile platforms would be the main suspects here.

However, these days, most of us assume that Javascript can be relied on, so a generic error message if server validation fails is fine.